# messages floats up and down before appending in react hook reactjs and socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am building a chat message app using functional react hook approach but each time I post message, the message either refreshes or floats up and down before it finally appends. if use class method, everything works fine.

here is class method which works fine and append new chat messages normally

```
class App extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
this.state = {

            chats: [],
        };


 this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

  this.socket.on('get_chat', function(msg){          
 this.setState({chats: [...this.state.chats, msg]});
        });


this.handleSubmit = event => {

    event.preventDefault();
socket.emit('post_chat', {
                chat_message: 'helloworld message'
            });

  };

// render goes here

}
```

**My Issue:**

here is ReactHook functional method which refreshes or floats the new chat message up and down before it appends it as a result, some messages are missed or replaced.

I think its this line that causes the problem

```
 const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```

**here is the code**

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import io from "socket.io-client";
const App = () => {

const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch content axio or ajax
  }, []);


  const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

  socket.on('get_chat', function(msg){          
 const newChats = chats;
  setChats(newChats.concat([msg]));
        });


  function handleSubmit(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
socket.emit('post_chat', {
                chat_message: 'helloworld message'
            });

  };


//Return content goes here


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I moved the code below inside handlesubmit function

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
```